# Is there any way to check whether a particular element has been clicked?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

Maybe my question sounds a bit generic, so let me be more clear.

I have a textarea that is hidden on blur, to be replaced by another div. To be more specific, the above textarea contains markdown code, and the div contains the parsed version of this code.

Now, I am trying to add a formatting toolbar on top of the textarea, but of course, when I click on that, the blur event is triggered and the textarea is hidden, which is not convenient at all.

So my question is whether it is possible at all to prevent the blur default behaviour only when the toolbar is clicked, and if so what's the best way to do that.

Comment: If you just want answer in yes or no then YES its possible. you just have to change onBlur property of textbox when someone clicks on toolbar.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Maybe I should have asked also how? Because that's exactly what I need to know. Any pointer to that direction is appreciated, as I'm still learning and I'm willing to do my homework. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: My previous solutions didn't cut it so let's try with something else. I'm not really fond in binding the `document` `click` event but in this case it might be the best solution since it seems that you are coding some kind of WYSIWYG-editor. You can possibly tweak it to use [`.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead.

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    if ($(e.target).closest("#container").length == 0) {
        // Target that was clicked is not inside the container, so we can hide or replace the textarea
        $("textarea").hide();
    }
});
```

You can try this out on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/5VmjF/).

Comment: why would you suggest him to use a default dom method when there is a jqury method for the same.
i.e use jquerys focus method instead of document.activeElement

Comment: @user350374, and how would one use the `.focus` method instead of my example? I use document.activeElement because there is no `:focus` filter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tested both suggestions, but as I understand, the activeElement method only returns a specific element if it's an input or textarea element (otherwise returns the body as in my case), and the blur event can only be bound to input and textarea elements as well.

Comment: @finferflu, oh yeah you are totally correct. I've remade my example and updated the answer accordingly. Does this work for you?

Comment: Thanks again for getting back to me. This method works very well, and so far it seems the most elegant solution. Thank you :)

Comment: @finferflu, good to hear that it works! I fooled around some more with the example. Check this [update](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/5VmjF/1/)

Comment: That's interesting, however I'm doing something slightly different here: when I double click on the div, it gets hidden, and the textarea is displayed again (I did manage to accomplish that at least :).